# How to delete element from cell arrays after comparisons without causing cell arrays to get empty?

Tags: arrays, matlab, set, cell-array

I created 1D array which shows words and in which sentences they occur. After that I took the intersection to show which word occurs with which each of other remaining words in sentence:

```
OccursTogether = cell(length(Out1));
for ii=1:length(Out1)
for jj=ii+1:length(Out1)
OccursTogether{ii,jj} = intersect(Out1{ii},Out1{jj});
end
end
celldisp(OccursTogether)
```

the output of above code is as below:

```
OccursTogether{1,1} =

 4 11 14

OccursTogether{1,2} =

 1
OccursTogether{1,3} =

 []
OccursTogether{1,4} =

 1 4 8 14 15 19 20 22

OccursTogether{1,5} =

 4 11
```

I want to check a single element if its deletion doesn't cause empty set it should be deleted but if its deletion give rise to empty set it should not be deleted.

for example:

`step1:`Delete 4 from `{1,1}`and`{1,5}` it will not be empty so 4 should be deleted.

`step2:` Delete 14 from `{1,1}`and`{1,4}` it will not be empty so 14 should also be deleted.

`step3:` If i delete 11 from `{1,1}`and`{1,5}` it will cause empty set because `4` and `14` are deleted in `step 1` and `step 2` so it should not be deleted.

Element deletion operations should be carried out for all the cells of the arrays.`OccursTogether` is declared as 1D cell array.

How can i code to make Comparisons and deletions for all `OccursTogether` cell array locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following, where `C` stands for your `OccursTogether` cell (shorter, thus easier to read for this answer). The comments in the code explain a bit what the corresponding lines do.

```
C = cell(3,2);

C{1,1} = [4 11 14];
C{2,1} = 1;
C{2,2} = [1 4 8 14 15 19 20 22];
C{3,2} = [4 11];
celldisp(C)

C = cellfun(@unique, C, 'UniformOutput', false); % remove duplicates from elements of C

numsInCell = unique([C{:}]); % numbers in cell, sorted

for n = numsInCell % loop over numbers in cell
    lSetIs1 = cellfun(@numel,C) == 1; % length of set is 1
    nInSet = cellfun(@(set) any(set==n), C); % set contains n
    nIsUnique = sum(nInSet(:))==1; % n occurs once
    condition = ~nIsUnique & ~any(nInSet(:) & lSetIs1(:)); % set neither contains n and has length of 1, nor n is unique
    if condition % if false for all sets...
        C = cellfun(@(set) set(set~=n), C, 'UniformOutput', false); % ... then remove n from all sets
    end
end

celldisp(C)
```

Notice I use logical indexing in the line in the `for`-loop starting with `C = cellfun(...`, which saves you an additional `for`-loop over the elements of `C`. The MATLAB function `cellfun` performs the function handle in its first argument on the elements of the cell in the second argument. This is a very useful tool that prevents the use of many `for`-loops and even some `if`-statements.

Comment: thanks for your answer, But i need a generalized way to remove any element from the array after comparing it with all the other cell array elements and delete it from all the locations after checking if its deletion does not lead to empty set. in my above code i want to pass `OccursTogether (1D array [1 cross N])`  and by the help of loop it should compare check emptiness constraint and delete accordingly - i hope you understand my point..

Comment: What do you mean by ‘empty set’? Is a set a single element of the cell array (e.g. [4 11 14] in your example) or is the entire cell array the set that should not be emptied? And I don't understand what the problem is you have with steps 1, 2, 3 you give as an example. Is it an example of the intended behaviour? Because then you can use my method to first remove 4s, next remove 14s and then remove 11s. You will see the remaining single 11 will not be deleted. If I haven't understood you, please explain a bit more and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: you interpreted my problem differently, in my example `OccursTogether{1,1}= { 4 11 14 }` i have a cell `{1,1}` having values `4 11 14` stored same as array index locations and so on till `OccursTogether{n,n}= (can be any set of  integers)` I want to compare values of the right hand side e.g pick only `4` from `{1,1}` and compare it with all the values till `OccursTog{n,n}=` and check if deletion of 4 causes empty set at any location if yes don't delete that particular element and pick another one from `{1,1}` which is `11` start again and compare 11 with every value places at `{n,n}` location.

Comment: i am only calling values inside parenthesis `{..}` as sets so that u can easily understand but inside these parathesis every integer is stored at a separate array locaion. it is cells containing 1D arrays

Comment: Aha, so you don't want to remove any number `x` from any cell element if it causes any other element to become empty, am I right? I then have two questions about your method:
1: Do you want to do this for any value of `x` in your cell, or do you specify the numbers you want to remove?
2: In you example cell, index `{1,5}` contains 4 and 11. Depending on which number you'd start with, either, 4 or 11 will be removed from `{1,5}` first, which would leave the other behind not to be removed. Does this matter, or should this method account for that by preserving both 4 and 11 in `{1,5}`?

Comment: And if I have understood you correctly, then I believe that the example cell I presented in my current answer would become `{[2], [], [2], [1]}`. I.e. the 3 and 0 would be removed, because their removal doesn't cause any other element to become empty and 2 and 1 would remain, because their removal would cause any cell to become empty. Is this congruent with your problem?

Comment: yes u are rite, 1: I want to do this for any value of x in my cell i don't want to remove any specific numbers it could be any number x. 2: the number which comes first is the candidate for deletion i don't want to preserve any number like at location {1,1} and {1,5} 4 occurs first so 4 is candidate for deletion and after that we will check for 11 and so on till the last element...Exactly i want the same answer as you said in your 2nd comment you understood it rite