# Generalized method for deletion of any integer from cell arrays after comparisons in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells

This is a follow up question of [How to delete element from cell arrays after comparisons without causing cell arrays to get empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318379/how-to-delete-element-from-cell-arrays-after-comparisons-without-causing-cell-ar/29318802?noredirect=1#comment46834975_29318802) for which i got a partial solution. following is the code:

```
A = cell(2);
A{1} = [2 4];
A{3} = [3 2 0];
A{4} = 1;
celldisp(A) % A contains one 2, an empty cell, a double array and a 1.

AWithout2ButNotEmptied = cellfun(@(x) x( (x~=2) | (numel(x)<2) ), A,'UniformOutput', false);
celldisp(AWithout2ButNotEmptied)
```

output of above code is:

```
A{1,1} =
 2 4
A{2,1} =
 []
A{1,2} =
 3     2     0
A{2,2} =
 1
AWithout2ButNotEmptied{1,1} =
 4
AWithout2ButNotEmptied{2,1} =
 []
AWithout2ButNotEmptied{1,2} =
 3     0
AWithout2ButNotEmptied{2,2} =
 1
```

output shows that `A{1,1}` is equal to `4` and is not emptied after deletion of `2`, because its length is less than two (its length is one). `A{1,2}` has the element equal to 2 removed. `A{2,1}` is already empty and is left unchanged. `A{2,2}` has length 1, but is not equal to 2, so it is left unchanged as well so, the check is performed only on number `2` whether to be deleted or not.

How can i change this code to remove any number `x(not only 2)` from any cell element if it does not causes any other array to become empty.

I want to do this for any value of `x(1,...,n)` in my cell i don't want to remove any specific numbers it could be any number `x` from the cell arrays.

for example:

```
OccursTogether{1,1} =

4 11 14

OccursTogether{1,2} =

1
OccursTogether{1,3} =

[]
OccursTogether{1,4} =

1 4 8 14 15 19 20 22

OccursTogether{1,5} =

 4 11
```

the result i want is as follows;

```
OccursTogether{1,1} =

 11

OccursTogether{1,2} =

1
OccursTogether{1,3} =

[]
OccursTogether{1,4} =

1 8 15 19 20 22

OccursTogether{1,5} =

 11
```

as u can see `4` and `14` is removed from multiple cells which gave the above result. we cannot remove `11` because it will cause empty location at `{1,1}` and `{1,5}` same checks should be applied on every number `x` before removing it.

Comment: and you want to start with **1**, then **2** and so on, up to **n**? So your final result is just one element in every cell?

Comment: @thewaywewalk i want to start with the first element of first cell array as u can see in example `A{1,1}=[2 4]` it can be any set of integers i want to start with first element only which in my case is `2` but it can be any integer so,compare it with the rest of the array elements as it is done above and go for `4` and so on till every element is compared and checked.

Comment: @thewaywewalk and the final result is not necessarily to be one element in every cell it should not be empty rest it can be multiple

Comment: Could you add an example where the result has more than one items? I think that would be useful as well...

Comment: @kkuilla i've added an example in the question please see the updated question- thanks

Comment: If you really want to remove numbers by order of appearance in the cell array, I really don't see a better option than going cell by cell and element by element and trying to remove them with the `cellfun` call you have. I would keep a list of all cells which currently only contain one element, and check only them to see if a number can be removed. Then after removal I would update this list. I would also keep a list of all numbers which I already tried to remove, so I won't try to remove them twice.

Comment: @Naveh actually i have large number of data almost `36 cells` each having diffrent size of arrays as shown in my sample example so it is difficult to go cell by cell manually and check for numbers, if u can help me optimizing this code with `for loop` it would be helpfull, thanks

Comment: Obviously I meant using a loop and not doing it by hand, as the answers now posted here do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29318802/3169029) is updated now.

I copied it here:

---

Use the following, where `C` stands for your `OccursTogether` cell (shorter, thus easier to read for this answer). The comments in the code explain a bit what the corresponding lines do.

```
C = cell(3,2);

C{1,1} = [4 11 14];
C{2,1} = 1;
C{2,2} = [1 4 8 14 15 19 20 22];
C{3,2} = [4 11];
celldisp(C)

C = cellfun(@unique, C, 'UniformOutput', false); % remove duplicates from elements of C

numsInCell = unique([C{:}]); % numbers in cell, sorted

for n = numsInCell % loop over numbers in cell
    lSetIs1 = cellfun(@numel,C) == 1; % length of set is 1
    nInSet = cellfun(@(set) any(set==n), C); % set contains n
    nIsUnique = sum(nInSet(:))==1; % n occurs once
    condition = ~nIsUnique & ~any(nInSet(:) & lSetIs1(:)); % set neither contains n and has length of 1, nor n is unique
    if condition % if false for all sets...
        C = cellfun(@(set) set(set~=n), C, 'UniformOutput', false); % ... then remove n from all sets
    end
end

celldisp(C)
```

Notice I use logical indexing in the line in the `for`-loop starting with `C = cellfun(...`, which saves you an additional `for`-loop over the elements of `C`. The MATLAB function `cellfun` performs the function handle in its first argument on the elements of the cell in the second argument. This is a very useful tool that prevents the use of many `for`-loops and even some `if`-statements.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates from the cell, just like in thewaywewalk's answer, then you could use `C = cellfun(@unique,C,'UniformOutput',false)` before using my method. Curious detail: the empty `[]` element becomes an `Empty matrix: 0-by-1`, which basically is the same.

Comment: thank you so much for such a perfect code it's working with the example but there is a slight issue when i change `C` with `OccursTogether` it gives an error which is `Error using cat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent` and                 `Error in cell2mat (line 84)
m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});`

Comment: i declared `OccursTogether` as `OccursTogether = cell(length(Out1));` Out1 is a 1D array which is constructed as `Out1 = cell(numel(out_words), 1);`

Comment: Try using `numsInCell = unique(cell2mat(C(:)));` (I added `(:)` after `C`). Right now I can't check with MATLAB if this works, but it might help. This helps if cell `C` is not a vector, but a matrix, i.e. it has 2 dimensions that are greater than 1. `C(:)` vectorizes `C`, so that the function `cell2mat` can simply concatenate each cell in `C` to one long vector.

Comment: It works fine if i copy paste your code but still gives the same `Dimensions of matrices been concatenated are not consistent` error when i change `C`, in my workspace `OccursTogether` is `<10x1 cell>` cell array its not 2 dimension. i'll play around to figure out how to fix it in the mean while you also check when u are free - thanks

Comment: This is because my code apparently only works with a row vector cell (i.e. 1×n), which is my bad. I've update the code, now it accepts any dimension cell.